# Vim Foo, List to Html Table

Tags: vim

What is the easiest way in Vim to go from:

```
hello
world
test
test2
test3
test4
```

to

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>world</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td>test2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test3</td>
<td>test4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For a list of arbitrary length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add <table> and </table> manually:

`ggO<table>[ESC]YGpa/[ESC]`

Where [ESC] is the top-left key on your keyboard +)

1. gg - go to the top of the file
2. O - add new line above the current
3. <table> - write <table>
4. [ESC] - back to the command mode
5. Y - yank current line
6. G - go to the end of the file
7. p - paste yanked line below the current
8. a - begin insert mode and start inserting after current symbol
9. / - add / symbol
10. [ESC] - back to the command line

Now u can record a short vim macros to repeat another set of command multiple times:

`:2[ENTER]qqO<tr>[ESC][DOWN]I<td>[ESC]A</td>[ESC][DOWN]
I<td>[ESC]A</td>[ESC]o</tr>[ESC][DOWN]q`

yep, now u can just repeat `@q` multiple times...(e.g. `11@q`)

1. :2 - go to the second line in the file
2. qq - start recording macros in 'q' register
3. O - add new line above the current
4. <tr> - add <tr>
5. [ESC][DOWN] - you know =)
6. I - go to the begining of the line and start the insert mode
7. <td> - write <td>
8. [ESC] - ...
9. A - go to the line end and start the insert mode
10. </td> - ...
11. [ESC][DOWN]
12. repeat 6-10
13. [ESC]
14. o - add line below current and start the insert mode
15. </tr> - ...
16. [ESC][DOWN]q - end macros recording

Comment: im accepting this, though the full regex solution would be interesting as well

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for [zen-coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) for [vim](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/issues/detail?id=16).

Comment: +1, might not be exactly what the OP is looking for, but this looks awesome!

Comment: +1 zen coding suits this job . it'll increase your speed in coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you're probably thinking of some clever solution using macros, but I'd let my fingers do the walking (since you're not likely to have an HTML table hundreds of lines long):

For each line of the file, replace the beginning of line with `<td>`
And for each line, replace the end of line with `</td>`

```
%s/^/<td>/
%s/$/<\/td>/
```

goto the first line and insert

```
</tr>
<tr>
```

Yank those lines, press down-arrow until you're at the next insertion point and press `p`
Continue to the bottom of the file, pressing `p` every two lines. There's a simple kind of rhythm here that I like to use: down, down, p, down, down, p, etc.

Change the last line to

```
</table>
```

Go back to the top and change the first line to

```
<table>
```

Obviously, I *haven't tried this* (and I concede that macros might be easier for some)